# Compiling function solving for the smallest eigenvalue of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, compile

I am trying to speed up my code, which many times finds a lowest eigenvalue of a Hermitian (symmetric, real) matrix. Using a small 2x2 matrix as an example, this works:

```
Energy = Compile[{{matrix, _Real, 2}}, Min[Re[Eigenvalues[matrix]]], {{Eigenvalues[_], _Complex, 1}}];
Energy[{{1, -2}, {-2, 3}}]
-0.236068
```

I have to use `{{Eigenvalues[_], _Complex, 1}}` here, otherwise Mathematica skips using the compiled function because of a type mismatch. Function Eigenvalues by default returns a vector of complex eigenvalues.

It should be in principle possible to compile a faster version, since I am only interested in the smallest eigenvalue, using `Eigenvalues[matrix, -1]`, which only solves for one eigenvalue. However, I can't seem to make it to work:

```
Energy = Compile[{{matrix, _Real, 2}},Eigenvalues[matrix, -1][[1]], {{Eigenvalues[_], _Complex, 1}}];
Energy[{{1, -2}, {-2, 3}}]
During evaluation of CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
2 - Sqrt[5]
```

Where am I making a mistake?
Also, is there a room for possible speedup if I somehow convince Mathematica, that I am only using Hermitian matrices and therefore expect only real eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the output of `CompilePrint[Energy]`:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint[Energy]


        1 argument
        1 Real register
        3 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(R2)0 = A1
        Result = R0

1   T(C1)1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Eigenvalues][ T(R2)0]]
2   T(R1)2 = Re[ T(C1)1]
3   R0 = MinRT[ T(R1)2]]
4   Return
```

The line `MainEvaluate[ Hold[Eigenvalues][ T(R2)0]]` means that the compiled program still needs to ask the main kernel to compute the `Eigenvalues`. This means that you gain nothing from compiling here at all. Looking at the [list of compilable functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) we confirm that `Eigenvalues` is not there.

**Solution**

The speediest way I know of finding eigenvalues in *Mathematica* is simply to give `Eigenvalues` a machine-number matrix:

```
Eigenvalues[N @ {{1, -2}, {-2, 3}}, {-1}]
```

This takes no measurable time on my laptop, while

```
AbsoluteTiming[Eigenvalues[{{1, -2}, {-2, 3}}, {-1}]]
```

shows 0.022 seconds. The reason is that `Eigenvalues` works differently for exact and numerical matrices. For a matrix with exact entries (like `{{1, -2}, {-2, 3}}`) `Eigenvalues` will interpolate the characteristic polynomial of the matrix and look for roots of that polynomial. When given a matrix with machine numbers on the other hand, *Mathematica* uses the *very* fast ARPACK library, which uses Arnoldi methods to find eigenvalues. I'm not too familiar with ARPACK, but I'm guessing it also specializes to the Lanczos algorithm when the input is Hermitian (see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html) for more info, e.g. Ctrl+F Eigenvalues)

Give this a go, and if you still need more speed, there are probably other places in the code that is slowing it down. Then we would need more details in order to help you ;)

Comment: I regard this as a definitive answer to the question that was asked. I will also raise the issue of what is the underlying goal? Is it to do some sort of quadratic optimization? If so, there might be alternative approaches.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, thanks for the comment!

Comment: You are welcome. I just hope others read and upvote your response, but skip my remark (other than the OP). I'd hate to discourage others, on the off chance that there is more to be said. (I don't think there is, but I've been wrong any number of times on that score.)

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Indeed, `Eigenvalues` gains no speedup when compiled. I have a followup question, though. I am still using `Compile` for the construction of the matrix, whose eigenvalue I'm looking for, and I need to minimize the eigenvalue. This fails because of symbolic evaluation. Since I'm not compiling `Eigenvalues`, I can't use `RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`. What can I do there?

Comment: Extension of the minimal working example above: `Matrix = Compile[{a}, {{a^2, -2}, {-2, 3}}];
Energy[a_] := Eigenvalues[Matrix[a], -1][[1]];
FindMinimum[Energy[a], {a, 1}]
During evaluation of CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument a at position 1 should be a machine-size real number. >>
{4., {a -> 1.14195*10^-12}}`

Comment: This warning actually only shows up because `FindMinimum` first tries to see what it can do with `Energy[a]` for a symbolic `a`. When that doesn't work, it continues by finding the minimum numerically using the default `Method`. If you want to avoid the warning, define `Energy` only for numeric arguments: `Energy[a_?NumericQ] := ...`

Comment: However, numeric minimization is not guaranteed to give a global minimum. And in your case, the value of the lowest eigenvalue can have jumps or discontinuities as you vary `a`, because `Eigenvalue` sorts on the **magnitude** of the eigenvalues. So in your case I would do `minEnergy[a_?NumericQ] := Min[Eigenvalues[matrix[a]]]` and `FindMinimum[minEnergy[a], a]`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, however in my case all eigenvalues are positive, so the eigenvalue with the smallest magnitude is also the lowest. Anyway, using `?NumericQ` works perfectly, thank you very much for all your help!